# Which device resolutions should be kept in mind when developing Android Apps?

Tags: android

I am total newbie to Android but I have some knowlege of iPhone apps.

In iPhone, we develop our app keeping iPhone / iPad's resolution in mind.

In Android, which devices should we keep in mind as there are so many models which runs on Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Pn Android, you focus on screen sizes (small, normal, large, etc.) and densities (low, medium, high, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Like iPhone, Android doesn't have any standard resolution to make any application.*

*But yes in Android you have option to keep your UI (layouts) or images (drawable) with different sizes to handle any resolution.*

One of the challenges that you will encounter during your time as an Android app developer is developing for multiple screen sizes. There are many things to keep in mind during your adventure into screen sizes. The following list below should help keep you on track.

1. The size requirements for each icon in each density vary for each
   type of icon. You find launcher icons, menu icons, status bar icons,
   tab icons, and many more. They are all built differently for each
   screen density. When building these icons, reference the [Android
   Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).
2. Try to always use the density-independent pixel (dip) measurement
   unit when defining your user interface. This helps your application
   scale to different devices. The density-independent pixel is a
   virtual pixel that scales proportionally for each given screen
   density.
3. Provide the [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) element to the AndroidManifest.xml file
   to help the Android market determine whether your application is
   compatible with various screen sizes.
4. Provide graphics for high-, medium-, and low-density devices. While
   this may increase your development and design time, it will greatly
   improve the usability and appearance of your application.

Here are some tutorials :-

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Designer’s Guide to Supporting Multiple Android Device Screens](http://anidea.com/technology/designer%E2%80%99s-guide-to-supporting-multiple-android-device-screens/)

[Designing For Android Tablets](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/09/designing-for-android-tablets/)

[Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

***And must read*** [Android Design Patterns](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/)

Hope this will help.

***And [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) is best online tool to create Android application graphics assets.***

Answer (score 1):

Answer is, **Nothing About Resolution to keep in mind** while developing.. Android is built in such a way

that it adapts to all resolutions if hardware is compatible..

Comment: so will the layout which we design for one device work for another? say I designed layout for Samsung Galaxy tab. Will it look fine in any android phones?

Comment: About tablet i'm not sure.. but for phones it will work fine.. since it uses "dp" and "dip" units...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following reading, it should help you to get an overview on how Android handle various resolutions.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Google stats](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html). Although it says that 90% of screens are Normal (at least 320x480) most of them are 400x800 and 400x854 ([source](http://www.enterra-inc.com/techzone/android_statistics/))

Comment: How do you know which resolution ranges correspond to the 4 labels used (Small, Normal, Large, XLarge) in the [Google stats](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) table you mentioned ? For example, how do you know Normal = at least 320x480 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an app using the standard view controls, the dip and dp answer is correct.

However, if you plan to design a game you will probably use the surfaceview and do all the drawings yourself (because this is the fastest way if you want a good framerate). Then you also need to scale everything you draw yourself. My way of doing this is to use the screen widht / height and a percentage whenever I need to draw something. Never use pixels. E.g. don't draw a circle with a 32px radius (if you're trying on a 320x480 screen). Draw a circle with a (screenWidth * 0.1f)px radius. Use this for texts size, bitmaps etc.