# Which screen resolution should i consider while designing an android application?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have searched for a while, to know which screen resolution i should consider before starting to design an android app.

I found these things:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

[Which device resolutions should be kept in mind when developing Android Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092744/which-device-resolutions-should-be-kept-in-mind-when-developing-android-apps)

but actually these are not what i wanted.

what i wanted to know is should i design my application for each of these resolution or take the most used resolution alone into consideration

or

if i am not using any hardcoded values for widths, heights and margins etc.., i never need to worry about the screen resolutions

or

how good is this - find the device width and height using Display metrics and create all views according to these values *Dynamically* ?

Comment: You should design your application to be resolution-independent, the way desktop and Web developers have done for a couple of decades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I design my application for each of these resolution or take the most used resolution alone into consideration.

You should make sure your application works correctly on *all* screens, not just the most popular one. I would begin from the bottom up... first make sure it works correctly on small/normal screens (and in doing so, you make sure it works on all screens). Then you can optimize your layouts for tablets by using multi-pane layouts, etc.

> If I am not using any hardcoded values for widths, heights and margins etc., I never need to worry about the screen resolutions.

Not sure what you are trying to say here, but you should *always* be wary about different screen resolutions by using `dp` (density independent pixels) instead of `px`.

> Find the device width and height using Display metrics and create all views according to these values dynamically?

This should be a last resort. Most of the time, your layouts won't be that complicated though, and it won't be necessary. A lot of the time you'll use `wrap_content` and `match_parent` to set the widths/heights, and often times you'll use `RelativeLayout`s to space the views relative to one another. You only really need to measure the widths/heights of the views if you find its absolutely necessary.

Comment: by the 2nd point i mean....using only wrap content, fill parent, match parent etc.., instead of 10dp/10px

Comment: You should never use `px`, as it doesn't scale well for devices w/ different densities. Its ok to use `dp` as long as it isn't ridiculous. i.e., if you have a button whose width is `20dp`, that's perfectly fine in 99% of cases. You just need to be aware of the boundaries... i.e., if you set the width of a button to go off the edge of the screen, that's when you would want to use display metrics to check the width of the screen, for example. But again, this shouldn't be a problem too often. This is another reason why simple layouts w/ less views makes your life easy :)

Comment: okay...so using dp alone will solve my problem?...thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, using `dp` is density independent and will make your layout consistent across devices w/ different densities. This is why using `px` is bad practice... because different devices (w/ different densities) represent pixels in different ways. `100 px` on a high-res device could be a half of an inch, whereas the same `100 px` on a low-res device could be 2 inches. Well, maybe the measurements are a bit unrealistic, but you get the idea :). Glad it helped.

Comment: btw, I assume you have read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: actually i asked a graphics designer to design screens for my application. He asked me "are we targeting 320x480 resolution?". So i started searching about it. So what must me the answer?....i think after this discussion it actually doesn't matter for him, it all depends on how i code it in the application following his screens?? right?

Comment: I don't know why he needs to know the exact number of pixels... as far as I'm concerned, all he really needs to do is design a layout that works well on a rectangular screen, right? It'll be your job to make sure it works for multiple Android devices... the graphics designer should only really be responsible for the layout. You should also make sure he is familiar with Android navigation/guidelines, as described in the "design" section of the developers site. Also... maybe he was just asking for the aspect ratio, not the exact # of pixels.

Comment: but when i am using images in my application, i need to  design images for all the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and keep them in there respective resource folders??...and when i use @drawable/myImage, in my code it automatically gets the image depending on the device pixel density?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, that is correct. `mdpi` and `hdpi` are the most important, and cover most devices, but it's good practice to cover all devices. [**This website makes handling icons incredibly easy.**](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you should always code your application such that every device is supported. From the launcher icon which is detailed here (different resolution for different screen size): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html to the layout of your app which should be designed so that everything is placed relative to the screen size (by using attributes such as match_parent and wrap_content).

You can try to code it such that the views are created dynamically after discovering screen size, but I think its easier and just as effective to do your first idea!

Comment: so you are elaborating my 2nd point right? if i understood your answer correctly

Comment: Yes, this one "if i am not using any hardcoded values for widths, heights and margins etc.., i never need to worry about the screen resolutions"

Answer (score 3):

Best option is to get the screen width and height dynamically using simple height and width getting parameters.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

other option is to do create it for device with highest screen width and height and then handle it mathematically for respective screen size.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is recommended to design for all the sizes. But I know it is a lot of overhead.

So what you could do is design for the largest device you're aiming for and have the devices adjust the images based on their sizes. Do not use hard coded values. Use `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`.

And yes, dynamically adjusting the images is a good idea, even though it requires more coding on your side. This is the technique I use.